# Actionscript error 1176: Comparison between a value with static type Number and a possibly unrelated type String?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

For lines 18 and 24 Actionscript seems to be unhappy with my if statements. Being really new to this I don't know how to rectify the issue if any.

```
var strName:String;
var strSystem:String;
var strHeight:String;
var numHeight:Number;
var numSystem:Number;
var strOut:String;
var strOut2:String;

enter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    strName=txt_Name.text;
    strSystem=txt_System.text;
    numSystem=Number(strSystem)
    strHeight=txt_Height.text;
    numHeight=Number(strHeight);

    if (numSystem == "M"){
        var numWeight:Number= numHeight*numHeight*25;
        var strWeight:String=String(numWeight);
        strOut=strName+ "'s ideal weight is" +strWeight+"kilograms.";
        txt_Answer.text=strOut
    }
    if (numSystem == "I"){
        var numWeight2:Number= (numHeight*numHeight*25)/703
        var strWeight2:String=String(numWeight);
        strOut2= strName+"'s ideal weight is" +strWeight2 + "pounds";



}
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What is with 
   `}
   {
   }
   }`
   at the end of your class? It's wrong as the middle `{}` does not start with any condition statement.
2. `var strWeight:String=String(numWeight);` should be var `strWeight:String= numWeight.toString();` or `var strWeight:String= numWeight.toFix();`

Comment: I kept on getting "1084: Syntax error: expecting right brace before end of program." without it. Any thoughts as to why? I've only been doing programming for a few days.

Comment: Like I explained, you have extra brace { in your class. If you are new to programming, the best way is to count the openning { and closing }. They need to be a pair, 1 openning { needs 1 closing }.

Comment: 1. I'm sorry I was in highschool when I made this post.